# TEXT() Function With Format Dynamically Defined in Another Cell

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula

As an example, suppose I had the following in an Excel 2010 worksheet:

```
A1:  1
B1:  2
C1:  "0.00"
```

And then I had this formula:

```
D1:  =TEXT(A1+B1, C1)
```

The output for D1 becomes:

```
D1:  0.00
```

In other words, D1's output becomes **the actual text in cell `C1`**

However, if I change D1 to:

```
D1:  =TEXT(A1+B1, "0.00")
```

Then, the output for D1 becomes:

```
D1:  3.00
```

As it should be.

Is there any way to define the format for a function output dynamically (As would have been the case had `TEXT(A1+B1,C1)` actually worked)?

I know I could probably write a quick VBA solution, but the person I'm working with is afraid of VBA, so I'm firstly wondering if Excel has any other ways of achieving this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format cell under C1 as Text and paste 0.00 in there (without quotes). At least that worked for me

Comment: Likewise '0.00 (note the apostrophe) will work too should you expect the cell format to change for any reason, either way is just as good.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, do not use quotes, and format the cell containing the format-text as text.  Optionally, apply a leading '.